# Socket error with sending/receiving

Tags: java, sockets

If I send a message, it will only be printed out by the server if I run it in a loop.

I tried to send the message after 1 minute, send it 50 times, but nothing will print it out on the server side.

What is my error?

Here is my code, it was written in Netbeans:

```
package me.jackboyplay.sockets_client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author JackboyPlay
 */
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 5001);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(socket == null){
            return;
        }
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        PrintWriter dos = null;
        try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dos = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        int x = 0;
        Long l = System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5);
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            dos.write("X: " + i);
        }
    }

}
```

```
package me.jackboyplay.jc_cloudsystem.mechaniken;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author JackboyPlay
 */
public class SocketClient extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;

    public SocketClient(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("Ein Client wurde akzeptiert.");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br;
        PrintWriter pw;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            while(true){
                String line = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SocketClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Class 1 is the Client that sends a message to the server.

Class 2 is the Server that will print out the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is using `BufferedReader.readLine()`, but the client is not sending any line breaks, so `readLine()` never returns:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

The client should be using `PrintWriter.println()` instead of `PrintWriter.write()`:

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property `line.separator`, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

```
dos.println("X: " + i);
```

> Prints a String and then terminates the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

Alternatively, use `PrintWriter.print()` to write the values as needed, and then call `PrintWriter.println()` when finished:

```
dos.print("X: ");
dos.print(i);
dos.println();
```

Either way, you may also need to call `PrintWriter.flush()` to actually send the output over the wire:

```
dos.flush();
```

Comment: Worked after I've added flush()